# System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox does not contain the definition of Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need to get the text value from the textbox on the web form. In the documentation its mentioned that System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox has a property Text but I get an error when I try to use it.

```
string FieldName= "";
string FieldValue="";
if (inputValues[i] is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
{
  FieldName = inputValues[i].ClientID;
  FieldValue = inputValues[i].Text; // error
}
```

The error shown is `System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox does not contain the definition of Text`. How do I get the text value from textbox control ?

Comment: What is type of inputValues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `inputValues[i]` to a `System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox`. Then access the `Text` property:

```
FieldValue = ((System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox)(inputValues[i])).Text;
```